# Read git log in a cross-platform way for a Julia package?

Tags: julia

I have a Julia package that generates plots and I want to keep track of what version of this package generated each plot. I was planning to embed the last commit hash into the plot so I can easily see this. Is there a nice cross-platform way to do this?

I know I can shell out to git using `run` but that's not guaranteed to work. I was thinking that I could potentially use `Base.LibGit2`? But I'm not sure how to access git log using the [API](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/libgit2/).

Comment: I don't have an answer for the Git hash part, but I want to share the [VisualRegressionTests.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/VisualRegressionTests.jl) for future readers interested in similar visual tests with plots.

Comment: Are you aware of [Git.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/Git.jl)? You should get the current hash of head with `Git.head()`.

Comment: Can you trust that the git version is the same version that generated the plot?  For example, a local repo could be updated without "compiling" the new code into the executable.  Maybe the package should tell you what version it is by having its version "complied" into the executable code.

Comment: I think it might be sufficient to say that it's dirty in that case?